# JTable Unknown errors, what to do?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, loops, jtable

Hi guys i need to make a table for a project and im getting a load of errors such as "illegal start of type", " expected" and a lot of brackets and semicolons missing too, can you help me out.

The idea is to display all the elements in Teacher Objects in one table... Thanks

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;



    public class DisplayTeachers extends JFrame
    {
private JTable table;
private JFrame f;
private int i = EnterTeacher.getArrSize();

public DisplayTeachers()
{
    setLayout(newFlowLayout());
    String[] columnNames =  {"Name", "Surname", "ID", "Pay", "Subject"};



    for (int count = 0; conut <= i; count++)
            {
    Object[][] data = {

            {
                subteach[i].getName(),
                subteach[i].getSurname(),
                subteach[i].getID(),
                subteach[i].getPay(),
                subteach[i].getSubjectID(),
            };

                      }
            };

table = new JTable (data, columnNames);
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(550, 500));
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);

f = new JFrame(Teachers);

f.add(scrollPane);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setSize(550,400);
f.setVisible(true);


}

    }
```

Comment: This code looks like it was formatted by my dog.  The first thing to fix is the indentation of code blocks to make them consistent and logical.  That will likely point to the source of some of the errors.

Answer (score 2):

One of the issues in your code is semi-colon at end of for loop declaration:

```
for (int count = 0; conut <= i; count++);
            {
```

remove semi-colon from for loop

```
for (int count = 0; conut <= i; count++)
            {
```

Comment: Please remove semi-colon  at this curly brace. }; table = new JTable line also.